# React-Native NavigationActions vs The Navigation Prop

Tags: properties, react-native, navigation

In looking at the documentation at the [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions) website and I am having trouble distinguishing between the use of The Navigation Prop and Navigation Actions... they seem to be the same to me.

The Navigation Prop offers the following helper functions such as

`navigate`   `state`  `setParams` `goBack` and `dispatch`

NavigationActions offers the following functions, "which return an object that can be sent to the router using the navigation.dispatch() method", as stated by the react navigation site.

`Navigate` `Reset` `Back` `SetParams` `init`

To me it seems like a duplication -- are there different use cases for these and if so what are they?